# How to pass parameter from html to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to passing one to many parameters from html to jQuery?

The requirement is when a link on the page is clicked, toggle some text for this link, and hide text for other link(s), so I have the following jQuery:

```
$(link1).click(function(){
    $(hide1).hide(300, function(){
        $(hide2.hide(300, function(){
            $(toggle1).slideToggle(300);
        });
    });
});
```

If there's five links on the page, I need to repeat the above code 5 time. 
Any suggestion on how to cut down on repeated code? 
I was thinking of the following, but somehow not working.

```
function hideNShow(toggle1, hide1, hide2, hide3, hide4) {
    if(hide1) {
    $(hide1).hide(300, function(){
        if(hide2) {
        $(hide2).hide(300, function(){
            if(hide2) {
            $(hide2).hide(300, function(){
                if(hide3) {
                $(hide3).hide(300, function(){
                    if(hide4) {
                    $(hide4).hide(300, function(){
                        $(toggle1).slideToggle(300);
                    });
                    }
                });
                }
            });
            }
        });
        }
    });
    }
    return false;
};
```

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks,
June

Answer (score 2):

Use smart class names to greater effect. The following example has a set of links which display a corresponding paragraph when clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title></title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.togglers a').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // which number list item are we?
        var block = $(this).closest('ul').find('li').index( $(this).parent() );
        console.log(block);

        $('.blocks p').removeClass('visible').eq(block).addClass('visible');
    });
    </script> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
        .blocks p { display: none; }
        .visible { display: block !important; }
    </style> 
</head> 
<body> 

<!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960508/how-to-pass-parameter-from-html-to-jquery --> 

<ul class="togglers"> 
    <li><a href="#">Block 1</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Block 2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Block 3</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Block 4</a></li> 
</ul> 

<div class="blocks"> 
    <p>This is block 1.</p> 
    <p>This is block 2.</p> 
    <p>This is block 3.</p> 
    <p>This is block 4.</p> 
</div> 

</body> 
</html>
```

See the edit history for a version that is slightly less abstracted.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the links names in an array and iterating through them would help you

```
for (id in contentDivs) {
            if (id === selectedId) {
                tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
                contentDivs[id].className = 'cal';
            } else {
                tabLinks[id].className = '';
                contentDivs[id].className = 'cal hidden';
            }
```

That's what I use to do the same thing with tabs.

Answer (score 0):

This looks much more like a structural problem than a programming problem.  If I understand your problem correctly you have the following issue: "When a user performs action `X`, perform actions `Y1, Y2, Y3 ... Yn` in order."

It would be best if you created an series of small functions to perform the different actions (slide, hide, toggle, etc), a dispatch table to associated those functions with names, and an array of instructions.

You could even put them next to the link, with input tags:

```
<input type="hidden" class="instructions" value="hide:div3,hide:div4,hide:div6,show:div9,toggle:span7,slide:p9">
```

And then use jquery selectors to find the input associated with the just-clicked link, unpack it, and follow the instructions.  That way, your server can provide the information needed without cluttering up your page with too much autogenerated javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, here's my updated code that works:

```
$(function(){
    $('.myLinks a').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    var linkClicked = $(this).closest('ul').find('li').index( $(this).parent() );

     $(".linkMessage div").each(function (i) {
        if(!(i == selectedAccNav))
            $(this).hide(300);
        if(i == selectedAccNav)
            $(this).slideToggle(300);
    })
        return false;
    });
```

});

Thanks again for your help.

-June